# Factorial of a number display issues

Tags: java

I know how to code to find the factorial of a number:

```
   public static void factorialcalculations()
          {
   int usernumber, calculation, fact = 1;

   System.out.println("Enter an integer to calculate it's factorial");
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    usernumber = in.nextInt();

    if ( usernumber < 0 )
     System.out.println("Number should be non-negative.");
    else
    {
     for ( calculation = 1 ; calculation <= usernumber ; calculation++ )
        fact = fact*calculation;

     System.out.println("Factorial of "+usernumber+" is = "+fact);
     {
```

But what I need is for is to display what numbers it is being multiplied by for example if it was 5

I need it to display the factorial is: `5*4*3*2*1=120`

Comment: So what is your question? This is not a code generation site. People can help you if you have a specific question but nobody will simply write your code.

Comment: I'm not asking for it to be written, i just cant work out how to use that code to provide the factorial output as show.

I have managed it so it say Factorial of 5 is = 120 but not displayed as 5*4*3*2*1

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Comment: i have displayed proof in the code, that i have written so far. as i said im just struggling with the output format, needing to be for example the factorial is 5*4*3*2*1=120

Answer (score 0):

Use recursion. The value you want to display for n=1 is "1=". For any other n, it's "n*" + display(n-1).

display(2) => "2*" + display(1) => "2*1="

display(3) => "3*" + display(2) => "3*2*1="

and so on.

Comment: is there a easier way of doing it as you might not know what the user selects as a number

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of ways to do it. With your existing code you can print it within your existing loop. Recursive will be the elegant way to find the factorial.

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    System.out.print("factorial is : ");
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
        result = result * i;
        System.out.print(i!=1 ? (i+"*"): (i+"="));
    }
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}
```

PS: As a best practice you need to handle the all scenarios in here. (String/negative/.. inputs)

Comment: what would i add in to say it cant be a negative number

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you seem to be looking for man:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the number whose factorial is to be found: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    int result = factorial(n);
    System.out.println(getFactString(n,result));
}

public static int factorial(int n) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        result = result * i;
    }
    return result;
}

public static String getFactString(int n, int result){
    String output= "";
    int count = n;

    for (int i = count; i > 0; i--) {
        if (n==1) {
            output = output + n +" = ";
            break;
        }
        output = output + n+" * ";
        n--;
    }
    return output + result;

}
```

It's also possible to do this will StringBuilder as well. With the getFactorString() method, it doesn't matter what n is, you will get the correct string returned to display.